# Godot collision

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I have a player object which is a character2D node. Under it, I also have a area2D node. I want to be able to check if another character2d (a enemy in this case) collides with the player object. It prints CharacterBody2D:<CharacterBody2D#29578232986> when I run print(body) under the signal function connecting to the root character2d node of the player. Also if there are any alternate ways to do it, feel welcome to share.

I tried move_and_collide however, it wasn't working so I'm trying the area2d method

code for player charact

```
extends CharacterBody2D
var gravity = 500
var accel = 100
var move_dir = Vector2(0,0)
var move_angle = move_dir.angle()
var motion = 0
var decel = 100
var jump = 500
var jump_duration = 0.2
var jump_extend = 500
var bullet = preload("res://objects/bullet.tscn")
var cooldown = 0

func _ready():
    $AnimatedSprite2D.play("default")
    

func shoot():
    if cooldown <= 0 :
        var projectile = bullet.instantiate()
        projectile.global_position.x = $Marker2D.global_position.x
        projectile.global_position.y = $Marker2D.global_position.y 
        get_parent().add_child(projectile)
        cooldown = 0.5

func _physics_process(delta):
    motion = velocity.x
    
    #handling shooting
    if cooldown > 0:
        cooldown -= delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        shoot()
        
    er#falling
    if not is_on_floor():
        if velocity.y <= 5000 :
            velocity.y += gravity * delta
    
    #in air
    if not is_on_floor():
        accel = 50
        
    #on ground
    if is_on_floor():
        accel = 100
        velocity.y = 0
        gravity = 1000
        jump_duration = 5
        jump_extend = 500
    
    #movement
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion = min(motion - accel, -1000)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion = max(motion + accel, 1000)
    velocity.x += motion * delta
    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, 0.0 , atan(decel) * delta)
    
    
    
    #jump
    if is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
            velocity.y = -jump 
    if not is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
            if velocity.y < 0:
                if jump_duration > 0 and jump_extend > 0:
                    velocity.y -= jump_extend * delta
                    jump_duration -= delta
                    jump_extend -= 100 * delta
        if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up"):
            jump_duration = 0
            jump_extend = 0
    
        
    #fast fall
    if not is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
            gravity = 2000
    
    #stop at borders
    
    if global_position.x > 1280:
        global_position.x = 1280
    #get hit
    
    
    move_and_slide()
    


func _on_area_2d_body_entered(body):
    print(body)
    pass # Replace with function body.
```

enemy code

```
extends CharacterBody2D
var hp = 2
var gravity = 5000
var accel = 100
var move_dir = Vector2(-200,0)
var move_angle = move_dir.angle()
var decel = 30
var jump = 500
var jump_interval = randf_range(1,5)

func _ready():
    $AnimatedSprite2D.play("default")
    
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.x = move_dir.x
    jump_interval -= delta

    #falling
    if not is_on_floor():
        if velocity.y <= 5000 :
            velocity.y += gravity * delta

    #jump at on terval
    if jump_interval <= 0 and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = jump
        jump_interval = randf_range(1,3)
    if hp <= 0 :
        queue_free()
    move_and_slide()
```

player node tree
[image]